# Grouping relational data into a single Datatable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, oracle, datagridview

I'm developing a system using WinForms C#.

I have two relational tables:

```
USER_PROFILE
| ID | NAME |
  1    prof1

PERMISSIONS
| UPROFILE_ID | PERMISSION | 
      1           abc
      1           acb
      1           bca
```

I need to show the profiles on screen.
I dont know if it's the best fitting solution for my case, or how to implement it. My idea is to display in a DataGridView like this:

```
| Profile | Permission1 | Permission2 | Permission3 | 
   prof1        abc           acb           bca
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JOIN the tables and use the PIVOT construct

Comment: You can run a join on the tables in the data access code, either via SQL or via LINQ.  I like Randy's PIVOT idea for the data output.

Comment: Is there a set number of permissions?  Will everyone have the same number of permissions?  You may need to dynamically construct the columns in your datagridview.

Comment: Yes, the number of columns will variate, also i need to give name to the columns. I think the solution will probably be the construction of the datatable. That way the heavy logic will be on the code, not in the query. I'll google it, thanks.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to treat it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'case switch' to convert row into column. In actual select query you can construct column list dynamically.
Example:-

`SQL> select id,name from user_profile;`

```
    ID NAME
```

---

```
     1 U1
     2 U2
```

`SQL> select id,pname from per order by 1;`

```
    ID PNAME
```

---

```
     1 A
     1 B
     2 C
```

`SQL> select distinct u.name user_name, case when p.pname='A'then p.pname else null end permission1, case when p.pname='B' then p.pname else null end permission2 from user_profile u, per p where u.id=p.id order by 1;`

```
USER_NAME            PERMISSION1          PERMISSION2
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
U1                   A
U1                                        B
U2
```